# How old is the custom to eat dairy on Shavuos?

Tags: minhag, history, shavuos, dairy

I don't think I've ever seen a rationalization for this custom in works earlier than those of the Acharonim. I've never seen any Rishonim even mention it; certainly not earlier authors.

What's the earliest source we have for the eating-dairy custom? Or does anyone mention how old it is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The custom of eating dairy on Shavuos [is mentioned by several ראשונים](http://realiajudaica.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/dairy-on-shavuot.html) including:

- רבינו אביגדור צרפתי- probably the earliest source (12th century), [possible one of the בעלי התוספות](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F_%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%A7)
  *פירושים ופסקים לרבינו אביגדור הצרפתי על התורה (מהדורת הרשקוביץ, ירושלים תשנ"ו) פסקים תקצה-ח*
- [The Kol Bo (סימן נב)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15217&pgnum=219)
- [Orchos Chaim (הל' תפלת המועדים אות יג)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23994&pgnum=152)

Comment: Michoel, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for the informative answer! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Do you have a citation for where _Rabenu Avig'dor_ mentions this custom?

Comment: This is a great opportunity where translating Hebrew would elucidate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

although the custom is cited as regional minhag with different variations by several rishonim - some milk and honey etc, (as mentioned above) nevertheless the first to codify it as a minhag for yisrael was the rema in oc 494,3.
see [here](http://ohr.edu/5154)

Comment: great link! excellent article about "korban cheesecake". that author sure has a way with words!